# apache2 restart problem

Tags: server, apache2

When I restarted apache2 i got the below error.

```
$ sudo service apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2                                                                                                                                                              [fail]
 * The apache2 configtest failed.
Output of config test was:
apache2: Syntax error on line 140 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Action 'configtest' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

I also tried installing libapache2-mod-svn, got the below errors.

```
$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-svn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Suggested packages:
  db5.3-util
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libapache2-mod-svn
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/87.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 440 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-svn.
(Reading database ... 63832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-svn_1.8.10-1ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-svn (1.8.10-1ubuntu2) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Do you have [`libapache2-mod-svn`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=mod_dav_svn.so&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any) installed?

Comment: When I tried to install that I got the below error

Comment: 0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/87.7 kB of archives.
After this operation, 440 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Selecting previously unselected package libapache2-mod-svn.
(Reading database ... 63832 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libapache2-mod-svn_1.8.10-1ubuntu2_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libapache2-mod-svn (1.8.10-1ubuntu2) ...
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: I have updated my question muru

Answer (score 1):

The issue is fixed.

First I removed apache2

$ sudo apt-get remove apache2

then I installed libapache2-mod-svn

$ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-svn

This is how the problem is solved.

Thanks for your support guys.